# Overlay table with arrows

Tags: tables, arrows

I have a table that I want to overlay with arrows to show which cell in one column is connected to which cells to another column. Something like that:

[image]

Is this possible? I could use an external drawing app but this way the table would look inconsistent with the rest of the tables.

```
\begin{table} 
\centering 
\caption{BLAh-blah} 
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|} \hline 
AAA & 111 \\ \hline & 222\\ \hline
 BBB & 333\\ \hline
  & 444\\ \hline 
  CCC & 555\\ \hline \end{tabular}
\label{tab:tab1} 
\end{table}
```

Some people suggest I do it on TikZ. So, how do I do it there? I have never worked with Tikz before?

Comment: Draw the whole thing in tikz

Comment: Yes but that would change the letters, size of table compared to the other tables in the text. That offers no advantage over doing this in Visio or word and import the corresponding figure in the tex file.

Comment: How would using `tikz` change the letters? I believe it will offer an advantage over those tools, because the font will be the same and all the source can be stored in the LaTeX file...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something likes this. Basically use of `\tikzmark` and `\link` skill defined in the macros. Also, thanks to @AboAmmar for the `shorten >=xx pt' suggestion.

```
\newcommand\tikzmark[2]{%
\tikz[remember picture,overlay] 
\node[inner sep=0pt,outer sep=2pt] (#1){#2};%
}

\newcommand\link[2]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay, >=stealth, shorten >= 1pt]
  \draw[->] (#1.east) to  (#2.west);
\end{tikzpicture}%
}
```

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}

\newcommand\tikzmark[2]{%
\tikz[remember picture,overlay] 
\node[inner sep=0pt,outer sep=2pt] (#1){#2};%
}

\newcommand\link[2]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay, >=stealth, shorten >= 1pt]
  \draw[->] (#1.east) to  (#2.west);
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabular}{|M{2cm}|M{2cm}|@{}M{0pt}@{}} 
\hline
\tikzmark{a}{AAA} & \tikzmark{1}{111} &\\ [2ex]\hline 
                  & \tikzmark{2}{222} &\\ [2ex]\hline
\tikzmark{b}{BBB} & \tikzmark{3}{333} &\\ [2ex]\hline
                  & \tikzmark{4}{444} &\\ [2ex]\hline
\tikzmark{c}{CCC} & \tikzmark{5}{555} &\\ [2ex]\hline
                  &                   &\\ [2ex]\hline
\end{tabular}

\link{a}{1}
\link{a}{2} 
\link{b}{2}
\link{b}{4} 
\link{c}{1} 
\link{c}{5}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The appearance would be better if you add `shorten >= 2pt` as an option in your `tikzpicure`.

Answer (score 1):

With `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix` and TikZ to draw the arrows.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}

\begin{table} 
\centering 
\caption{blah-blah} 
\begin{NiceTabular}{cc}[columns-width=2cm,hvlines]
   AAA & 111 \\ 
       & 222 \\ 
   BBB & 333 \\ 
       & 444 \\ 
   CCC & 555 \\ 
\CodeAfter
  \begin{tikzpicture} [shorten < = 0.5mm, shorten > = 0.5mm, blue, ->]
  \draw (1-1) -- (1-2) ; 
  \draw (1-1) -- (2-2) ; 
  \draw (3-1) -- (2-2) ; 
  \draw (3-1) -- (4-2) ; 
  \draw (5-1) -- (1-2) ; 
  \draw (5-1) -- (5-2) ; 
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{NiceTabular}
\label{tab:tab1} 
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]